# Visual Studio Professional 2015 is not showing submit option for USQL & code is not in color format?

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to execute USQL code locally but code is appearing like simple text & submit option is disabled.

```
DECLARE @sliceDateYYYY string = @sliceDate.Substring(0, 4);
DECLARE @sliceDateMM string = @sliceDate.Substring(5, 2);
DECLARE @sliceDateDD string = @sliceDate.Substring(8, 2);
```

like above code, is simple black text. please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Please download and install the latest version of Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-data-lake-tools-get-started).

Azure SDK may be required also. Download it from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/tools/?v=17.23h).

Hope this helps.